# Cannot install express-generator globally with nvm

Tags: node.js, bash, express, nvm

I'm using NVM to avoid using `sudo` to install things globally. It works fine for everything from Bower, to Grunt, etc. However, when I do `npm install -g express-generator` it doesnt work. For example, heres what I get when I globally install Bower:

`npm install -g bower
/Users/jrdillon522/.node/bin/bower -> /Users/jrdillon522/.node/lib/node_modules/bower/bin/bower
bower@1.3.12 /Users/jrdillon522/.node/lib/node_modules/bower
├── is-root@1.0.0
...
...
...
├── update-notifier@0.2.0 (semver-diff@0.1.0, string-length@0.1.2, latest-version@0.2.0, configstore@0.3.1)
├── mout@0.9.1
├── handlebars@2.0.0 (optimist@0.3.7, uglify-js@2.3.6)
├── inquirer@0.7.1 (figures@1.3.3, mute-stream@0.0.4, through@2.3.6, readline2@0.1.0, lodash@2.4.1, cli-color@0.3.2, rx@2.3.14)
└── insight@0.4.3 (object-assign@1.0.0, async@0.9.0, chalk@0.5.1, os-name@1.0.1, lodash.debounce@2.4.1, tough-cookie@0.12.1, configstore@0.3.1, inquirer@0.6.0)`

Works fine right? When I install the Express Generator I get the classic error:

> npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.

So I run `sudo npm install -g express-generator`. Heres what I get then:

`sudo npm install -g express-generator
Password:
/Users/myName/.node/bin/express -> /Users/myName/.node/lib/node_modules/express-generator/bin/express
express-generator@4.9.0 /Users/myName/.node/lib/node_modules/express-generator
├── mkdirp@0.5.0 (minimist@0.0.8)
└── commander@1.3.2 (keypress@0.1.0)
➜  ~  express -v
zsh: command not found: express
➜  ~`

Why??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your bin path (`/Users/myName/.node/lib/node_modules/express-generator/bin/express`) isn't added to your environment.

If you modify your .bashrc file, add the following line to the bottom of your file to make things work as expected:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/Users/myName/.node/lib/node_modules/express-generator/bin
```

Then retry the installation.

Comment: So I actually had to add that to my `.zshrc` file but yeah, that worked. Its really odd that I had to and it probably means something is wrong. But that did fix it. Thanks!